# Different font/size with freetype (in pyopengl)?

Tags: python, opengl, fonts, freetype

For explanation I will use example "opengl.py" that goes with freetype-py-0.4.1 (just with little edit at the end, where I changed font):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy
from freetype import *
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import OpenGL.GLUT as glut

base, texid = 0, 0
text  = '''Hello World !'''

def on_display( ):
    global texid
    gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1)
    gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    gl.glBindTexture( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid )
    gl.glColor(0,0,0,1)
    gl.glPushMatrix( )
    gl.glTranslate( 10, 100, 0 )
    gl.glPushMatrix( )
    gl.glListBase( base+1 )
    gl.glCallLists( [ord(c) for c in text] )
    gl.glPopMatrix( )
    gl.glPopMatrix( )
    glut.glutSwapBuffers( )

def on_reshape( width, height ):
    gl.glViewport( 0, 0, width, height )
    gl.glMatrixMode( gl.GL_PROJECTION )
    gl.glLoadIdentity( )
    gl.glOrtho( 0, width, 0, height, -1, 1 )
    gl.glMatrixMode( gl.GL_MODELVIEW )
    gl.glLoadIdentity( )

def on_keyboard( key, x, y ):
    if key == '\033': sys.exit( )

def makefont(filename, size):
    global texid

    # Load font  and check it is monotype
    face = Face(filename)
    face.set_char_size( size*64 )
    if not face.is_fixed_width:
        raise 'Font is not monotype'

    # Determine largest glyph size
    width, height, ascender, descender = 0, 0, 0, 0
    for c in range(32,128):
        face.load_char( chr(c), FT_LOAD_RENDER | FT_LOAD_FORCE_AUTOHINT )
        bitmap    = face.glyph.bitmap
        width     = max( width, bitmap.width )
        ascender  = max( ascender, face.glyph.bitmap_top )
        descender = max( descender, bitmap.rows-face.glyph.bitmap_top )
    height = ascender+descender

    # Generate texture data
    Z = numpy.zeros((height*6, width*16), dtype=numpy.ubyte)
    for j in range(6):
        for i in range(16):
            face.load_char(chr(32+j*16+i), FT_LOAD_RENDER | FT_LOAD_FORCE_AUTOHINT )
            bitmap = face.glyph.bitmap
            x = i*width  + face.glyph.bitmap_left
            y = j*height + ascender - face.glyph.bitmap_top
            Z[y:y+bitmap.rows,x:x+bitmap.width].flat = bitmap.buffer

    # Bound texture
    texid = gl.glGenTextures(1)
    gl.glBindTexture( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid )
    gl.glTexParameterf( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.GL_LINEAR )
    gl.glTexParameterf( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.GL_LINEAR )
    gl.glTexImage2D( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.GL_ALPHA, Z.shape[1], Z.shape[0], 0,
                     gl.GL_ALPHA, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Z )

    # Generate display lists
    dx, dy = width/float(Z.shape[1]), height/float(Z.shape[0])
    base = gl.glGenLists(8*16)
    for i in range(8*16):
        c = chr(i)
        x = i%16
        y = i//16-2
        gl.glNewList(base+i, gl.GL_COMPILE)
        if (c == '\n'):
            gl.glPopMatrix( )
            gl.glTranslatef( 0, -height, 0 )
            gl.glPushMatrix( )
        elif (c == '\t'):
            gl.glTranslatef( 4*width, 0, 0 )
        elif (i >= 32):
            gl.glBegin( gl.GL_QUADS )
            gl.glTexCoord2f( (x  )*dx, (y+1)*dy ), gl.glVertex( 0,     -height )
            gl.glTexCoord2f( (x  )*dx, (y  )*dy ), gl.glVertex( 0,     0 )
            gl.glTexCoord2f( (x+1)*dx, (y  )*dy ), gl.glVertex( width, 0 )
            gl.glTexCoord2f( (x+1)*dx, (y+1)*dy ), gl.glVertex( width, -height )
            gl.glEnd( )
            gl.glTranslatef( width, 0, 0 )
        gl.glEndList( )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    glut.glutInit( sys.argv )
    glut.glutInitDisplayMode( glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | glut.GLUT_RGB | glut.GLUT_DEPTH )
    glut.glutCreateWindow( "Freetype OpenGL" )
    glut.glutReshapeWindow( 600, 100 )
    glut.glutDisplayFunc( on_display )
    glut.glutReshapeFunc( on_reshape )
    glut.glutKeyboardFunc( on_keyboard )
    gl.glTexEnvf( gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, gl.GL_MODULATE )
    gl.glEnable( gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST )
    gl.glEnable( gl.GL_BLEND )
    gl.glEnable( gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL )
    gl.glColorMaterial( gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, gl.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE )
    gl.glBlendFunc( gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA )
    gl.glEnable( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D )
    makefont( '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/UbuntuMono-B.ttf', 64 )
    glut.glutMainLoop( )
```

Everything works fine here, but when I add (the rest stays unchanged) after this line:
`makefont( '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/UbuntuMono-B.ttf', 64 )`
another line:
`makefont( '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/UbuntuMono-B.ttf', 32 )`
It will render font with resolution of 32 one but with size of 64 one, while (I think) it should just render the 64 one, because I only added characters at the end of opengl display list. By the way, if I switch those makefont(), it will render font with resolution of 64 one, but scaled to the size of 32 (looks worse than just 32 one). I think the problem might be on this line:
 `gl.glTexImage2D( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.GL_ALPHA, Z.shape[1], Z.shape[0], 0,
                     gl.GL_ALPHA, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Z )`
, but since I am quite new to opengl and freetype the problem might be elsewhere. Thank you!